# How to make a generic transition rule in Stylus

Tags: css, generics, stylus

I am trying to do a generic transition rule in Stylus. My function is working only particular. It returns to me a string **'all ease-in-out 0.2s'**  not a rule and it's not working in a browser because it is inside single-quotes.

Is it possible to return a pure css rule? Thanks for any help.

```
getTransition(affect = 'all', animationRule = 'ease-in-out', time = 0.2)
  return affect + " " + animationRule + " " + unit(time, 's')
```

call

```
transition: getTransition('opacity')
```

result

```
transition: 'opacity ease-in-out 0.2s';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes in the parameter when you call the function:

**Stylus**

```
getTransition(affect = 'all', animationRule = 'ease-in-out', time = 0.2)
  return affect + " " + animationRule + " " + unit(time, 's')

div
  transition: getTransition(opacity)
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
```